# how can we calculate the time difference of user actions on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have one php application..in that i display all questions with radio buttons as options..so when user start exam the timer will start on the top of the page like 00:00sec like this..

so i restrict the user to click radio button only 2 attempts..so i want to calcuate the time difference between thoswe two attempts..

like when user click radio buttton first time that time will store in database  and after user click second button calculate the difference between two attempts depending on my timer only..

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working as you expect it?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a vague question, I'm just a beginner, but what you could do is use getTime() method when he clicks the first time you use getTime() combined with "onclick" on your radio button, and you do the same for second time, then just do:

x = time2 - time1 = HowLongTimePassedBetweenThose2Clicks in ms

so if you do x / 1000 = TimeInSeconds

You can use if/else later to check if he did it in time or not.

Comment: yeah..i already use this but when i use getTime() it calculates current time..but i want to calculate time by using my timer only..

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to calculate time by using my timer only". Somewhere you need to retrieve the current time from which is "Date().getTime()"

Comment: for ex:when i click on first radio button the time is in my timer  00:05 and second time when i click on radio button the time is in my timer is 00:10:so i want to calculate these difference

Comment: To calculate the difference in seconds it only would be `var diff = (Date().getTime() - startTime) /1000`. Set a startTime when clicking  the first radio button and calculate the difference on the second click

Comment: How did you create the timer on your page, what did you use,new Date() and getTime() ?